# Tk is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

this opens a new window when the button Open is clicked but when the new window open nothing  is shown about password thing i put but i get tk is not defined
import tkinter as tk

```
        def Open():
            newWindow = tk.Toplevel(MyProgram)
            // right here Tk isnt defined but idk what to do ?
            top = Tk()
            // how tall the window should be  
            top.geometry("450x300")
            // label for username
            user_name = Label(top, 
                          text = "Username").place(x = 40,
            // fill in ur password                 y = 60)  
            user_password = Label(top, 
                              text = "Password").place(x = 40,
            //submit ur answer                         y = 100)  
            submit_button = Button(top, 
                               text = "Submit").place(x = 40,
            // for the username                       y = 130)
            user_name_input_area = Entry(top,
                                     width = 30).place(x = 110,
            // for the username                        y = 60)  
            user_password_entry_area = Entry(top,
                                         width = 30).place(x = 110,
                                                           y = 100)  
            // this is to finish it
            top.mainloop() 
        
        
        
       // this opens a window saying quit and Open 
        // name of tk
        MyProgram = tk.Tk()
        // frame for the window
        frame = tk.Frame(MyProgram)
        // to make frame work you add this
        frame.pack()
        // a button with quit on it to end the program
        button = tk.Button(frame, 
                           text="QUIT", 
                           fg="red",
                           command=quit)

        button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        slogan = tk.Button(frame,
                           text="Open",
                           command=Open)

        slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        
        MyProgram.mainloop()
```

when i run this it opens the first window which is QUIT and Open,Quit works but ,Open does open a new window but it doesn't show password and username because Tk is not defined
I don't know what I'm doing wrong can you help please?

Comment: Ummm.. ```#``` is for comments in python. Of course, you have imported ```tkinter``` as ```tk```. You haven't done a wildcard import. So you need to do ```tk.Tk()``` for the one inside the ```open``` function. Also, if  there is a ```Toplevel()``` already, why are you again using ```Tk()```. ```Tk()``` is a class in ```__init__``` file in tkinter folder

Comment: `tk.Tk` not just `Tk`

Answer (score 1):

`Tk` is a module of `tkinter` package, so you have to call it specifying the name of underlying package. Since you've imported `tkinter as tk`, try replacing:

```
top = Tk()
```

with

```
top = tk.Tk()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have done:

```
top=Tk()
```

You know that `Tk()` is a class in the `__init__` file in `tkinter` folder(Windows 10, I don't know about mac or linux).

At the top of the code, you have imported `tkinter` folder as `tk`. So whenever you want to use a class from it, you will use `tk.<widget>`.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

However, in your code, you just mentioned `Tk()`. Now, python doesn't know what are you trying to do. In your code, `Tk()` is neither a function, nor a class. Also, it doesn't know you are referencing it from `tkinter` folder.

Now that would have been True if you had done a wild-card import or you had imported everything.

```
from tkinter import *
```

The fix is:

```
top=tk.Tk()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got this problem try this:-

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk
root.mainloop()
```